# Would it be conceivably possible to write an Android emulator for iPad (or vice versa?)

Tags: android, ios

Given that IDEs like Flash are able to cross-compile the same code into device native code, I was wondering if it's even conceivably possible to write an Android app that would run iPhone applications, or vice versa? And if so, what would that entail?

Comment: Flagged for being overly broad.

Comment: how can it be "broad", it's a boolean question! It's either possible or it's not. if it's possible, then there's an answer as to HOW it's possible, if it's not possible, it's not possible.

Comment: Nobody can say definitely that it is impossible, nor definitely that it is possible, so the only real answer here is "Might be possible". This question provokes discussion, and hypothesis, and not a clear answer backed by experience or facts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceivably possible? Sure. You'd be writing an emulator for iOS. You can look at any other emulator in order to see roughly what that would entail. Reasonably possible though? If you had to ask this question, then highly unlikely for you. You'd have to either rewrite the whole of iOS on top of Android or emulate the actual hardware and try to get a dump of an iOS image (no doubt breaking the EULA). You'd also have many side issues to think about like performance and compatibility. If it were easy, someone would have done it already by now. It's a monstrous amount of work.

Comment: "for me" is a relative term... I'm an engineer, but I also have hiring capacity :) So, your answer was exactly what I am looking for, though I'm actually more curious to see if the reverse is possible (since that would be more useful to me), meaning to port Android emulation onto iOS.  I know it would be a violation of Apple EULA (that bothers me very little), and I doubt it would be in violation of anything Google cares about.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice the "vice versa" part. The other way *should* be (slightly) easier, as Android is open source. It's still a big project and you'll need some serious talent, but it's technically possible... You'll definitely want to hire some guys who have done a lot of reverse engineering and have written emulators before. Also you'll probably want to find some with ARM experience specifically.